# Selecting all the points in a ray

Tags: blender

So I'm accustomed to Lightwave where selecting a point in orthographic view selects all the points along that ray from the viewport. I've been watching videos of people using older versions of Blender and it seems like that was the default behavior before. Am I just missing a setting?

Steps to reproduce the problem using the latest version available on the site:

1. Open new project
2. Set view to ortho and front
3. Hit tab to enter edit mode on default Cube object
4. Right mouse click the top right vertici

Only the front most vertex is selected, rather than both.

Comment: Geoff, it helps us when answering questions if you give us feedback on the answers you receive. Comment on on what works and accept the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of Blender did have a toggle for this. I haven't found it in the new version. However, when I want to select multiple vertices behind, I use the box selection. Hit `b` for box selection mode, then click and drag around the forward most vertex. This will select everything in the box, including those behind.

Alternatively, you can hold shift and double right click, but that may only work with the front most and rear most vertices

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing to what you want that I know of is to activate circle select mode (keybind C), you also need to deactivate "limit selection to visible" if you want to use it in solid draw mode however. To change the circle size use your mousewheel.